# Linking Django QuerySets in a similar way to annotations

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have the following models:

```
class Foo(models.Model)
    bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class Bar(models.Model)
    ...

class Baz(models.Model)
    bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

I want to know if it is possible to do something similar to an annotation to link a `Baz` queryset to a pre-filtered `Foo` queryset. Something like:

```
queryset = Foo.objects.some_filter()
  .annotate(bazs=QuerySet('bar__baz_set.another_filter()'))
```

Note that the `Baz` queryset is also filtered, and that a `Bar` may not always have a `Baz`

This is what I hope to achieve in the template:

```
{% for foo in queryset %}
    ...
    {% for baz in foo.bazs %}
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is `prefetch_related` and [`Prefetch`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch)

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch
queryset = Foo.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'bar__baz_set',
        queryset=Baz.objects.filter(another_filter),
        to_attr='filtered_baz',
    )
)
```

This is how you'd use it in the template:

```
{% for foo in queryset %}
    ...
    {% for baz in foo.bar.filtered_baz %}
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried your solution, but I'm getting an error: `'Foo' object has no attribute 'filtered_baz'`.

Comment: @DanielH. The filtered set exists on `foo.bar`. I edited the solution.

Comment: The reason this is the better solution than you one you've decided to use is that this will only make 2 queries no matter now many `Foo` objects are returned. What you have will make N+1 queries. 1 for the Foo objects and then N more where N is the number of Foo instances returned so that it can fetch the `Baz` instances.

Comment: I see, thanks for pointing that out. I will make a note in the answer I posted. In my particular use case the number of `Baz` objects will be no more than 3, so it's not too much of an impact. But I will keep this solution in mind for the future.

Comment: It's the number of Foo objects that matter, not Baz.

Comment: Ah, okay, I misunderstood. Fortunately, the `Foo` objects are also few in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution which is more straightforward, but has in increased number of queries, as pointed out in the comments of the other answer.

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    ...
    @cached_property
    def bar_bazs(self):
        return self.bar.get_bazs_by_some_filter()

class Bar(models.Model):
    ...
    def get_bazs_by_some_filter(self):
        return self.baz_set.some_filter()
```

And in the template:

```
{% for foo in queryset %}
    ...
    {% for baz in foo.bar_bazs %}
        ...
```